# Variable changes value when using conditional breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using the Eclipse IDE to develop C++ code for an ARM (STM32) processor.  One of the options the debugger/Eclipse has is to set not only a  breakpoint, but a condition at which to break.  For example, "break at line 5 only if foo is 10."

However, when debugging in this way, I came across a problem where memory was changing unexpectedly.  Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "condition" field for a breakpoint allows you to write a C/C++ statement which will be evaluated to determine if the processor should be paused.

The fact that this can be **ANY** valid C/C++ statement can have some interesting (i.e., problematic) side-effects if you are not careful.

For example, consider the following code:

```
1: void foo(int a) {
2:     int b = a + 2;
3: }
```

If you want to break at line (2) only if `a` is equal to 10, make sure the condition is

```
a == 10
```

If you write

```
a = 10
```

for the condition, **the debugger will break at line (2) and set the value of a to 10**